# Assign values to new column with respect to values from other column does repeate or not

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My data frame is something like this, basically month wise user visits a site:

```
month user_id
 1     1
 1     2
 1     1
 1     3
 2     1
 2     2
 2     4
 3     2
 3     5
 3     1
```

I want to create a column having 0 or 1. Every user_id will get 1 only once and other time it will get 0.

*desire output example*

```
month user_id new_column
  1     1       1    
  1     2       1 
  1     1       0 
  1     3       1
  2     1       0 
  2     2       0 
  2     4       1 
  3     2       0
  3     5       1
  3     1       0
```

Comment: I do not see how the results are counts of users by month. They simply mark new users, regardless of the months.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need set to `0` duplicated values of column `user_id`:

```
df['new'] = (~df.duplicated('user_id')).astype(int)
```

Or:

```
df['new'] = np.where(df.duplicated('user_id'), 0, 1)
```

---

```
print (df)
   month  user_id  new
0      1        1    1
1      1        2    1
2      1        1    0
3      1        3    1
4      2        1    0
5      2        2    0
6      2        4    1
7      3        2    0
8      3        5    1
9      3        1    0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another piece of code using basic operations:

```
i=0
df['new']=""
#a new empty column
for a in range(len(df)):
    if(df.iloc[a,1]>i):
    #get a th index entry for user_id(1)
        df.iloc[a,2]=1
#set value to one
#a,2 means ath entry for 3 column (new)
        i+=1
    else:
        df.iloc[a,2]=0
```